# how to add google accouts package to my site built using telescope and meteor

Tags: telescope

Telescope allows to choose the only three Authentication Methods from admin settings panel. The three methods are through email/password, facebook, twitter. I would like to add google to the authentication methods.

My local copy of the sites folder has been deleted, otherwise I could have used the command "meteor add accounts-google" in terminal. I also tried executing the same command in the console, but its showing errors.

It would be helpful if any one could suggest adding google account as an authentication method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You deleted your development copy of the site?  That's a problem.  You're going to need a local development environment to make changes to the app and redeploy.

`meteor add accounts-google` and a redeploy is your solution.